# Hyperbolic Reflection of polygon

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, mobius-transformation, tiling, reflection

I'm working on visualizing the reflections of a polygon in the Poincaré disk along each side of it using SageMath. The figures below show the reflections of a polygon (a 4-gon and a 3-gon, the innermost ones around the origin), where some of the reflected polygons overlap. Do these look correct to you?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please. Specify what do you understand as hyperbolic reflection.

Comment: I can imagine an actual mathematical question along these lines, perhaps asking whether your procedure for drawing these pictures is correct. But at present your question, asking whether these "look correct", is rather too subjective for this site. As it says on [The Tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour), *Don't ask about questions that are primarily opinion based.*